# what next.js releases that were compatible with node.js14.17.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, json, npm

Received a react app but it failed to work problem being, old mac-book PC version that has no capability to use dependencies of latest next code.

tried installing current node hoping it would just work but it failed, looked for node version that works with my PC and got it though failed to retrieve information on next version compatible with node.js14.17.0

Comment: `it failed` - what failed? node? the app? the PC?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.